# How to use form validation for dynamic dropdown value by using codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Rules defined in Config folder/form_validation.php :

```
'add_company_feedback_by_employee_rules' => [
    [
     'field'  => 'company_feedback_improvement',
     'label'  => 'Organization feedback ',
     'rules'  => 'required'
    ],
    [
     'field'  => 'company_feedback_suggestion',
     'label'  => 'Suggestion ',
     'rules'  => 'required'
    ],

    [
     'field'  => 'company_feedback_employee',
     'label'  => 'Employee ID ',
     'rules'  => 'required|in_list[Annonymous]'
    ]
]
```

In view i am showing employee id dynamically in dropdown and there is also 
one field Annonymous which is static in dropdown:

```
<?php echo form_label('Employee ID', 'company_feedback_employee'); ?>
<?php 

$options = array(
    'null'  =>  'select',
    $employee_id => $employee_id,
    'Annonymous' => 'Annonymous'
);

$style = array(
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'name' => 'company_feedback_employee',
    'id' => 'company_feedback_employee'
);

echo form_dropdown('company_feedback_employee', $options, 
set_value('company_feedback_employee'), $style);

echo form_error('company_feedback_employee');?>
```

There is something wrong with this `in_list[Annonymous]`. I don't know, how 
can I validate `$employee_id` which is the dynamic value?

Comment: What is something wrong?

Comment: How can I use $employee_id in in_list[] ? While its working on static value Annonymous like in_list[Annonymous]

Comment: Please explain more in your question.